# RxJava 2 Zip/Combine/FlatMap operators

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm trying to find a proper RxJava 2 operator for my specific need.
I have 2 server requests.

```html
val singletonOne = repository.loadData(requestOne) // Returns Single
val singletonTwo = repository.loadData(requestTwo) // Returns Single

val combinedSingle = Single.zip(singletonOne, singletonTwo) { responseOne: MyResponse, responseTwo: MyResponse
  CombinedResponse(responseOne, responseTwo)
}
```

Then I'm subscribing to my combined Single and can handle 2 responses extremely racting them from CombinedResponse.

```html
RxUtil(schedulers).observe(combinedSingle).subscribe(combinedResponse -> { 
view.updateSmthOne(combinedResponse.firstResponse.data)
view.updateSmthTwo(combinedResponse.secondResponse.data)
}, {/*Handle error*/})
```

Everything is fine wit this approach. But now I need to add one small change.
I need to get one field from the **1st response** use it to update one field of the **2d request** and as a result I should get the same CombinedSingle.
I went through RxJava 2 docs and could not find proper operator which could solve my problem.

**Note**

Yes, I can subscribe to the 1st single, get it's result and on onSuccess(...) make 2nd server request with updated field. That works, but I'm looking for better solutions with RxJava.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: Hi @akarnokd, thanks for the very useful link. Combining flatMap and map operators solved my issue.
`val singleToEvaluate = repository.loadData(requestOne)
.flatMap { firstResponse ->
/* Here we can extract data from the first response and use it to create 2nd request*/
requestTwo.field = firstResponse.fieldForSecondRequest
repository.loadData(requestTwo)
.map { secondResponse ->
CombinedResponse(firstResponse, secondResponse)
}
}
RxUtil(schedulers).observe(singleToEvaluate).subscribe(/*......*/)
`